# Would Hank have been able to let Walter Jr. off for attempting to buy alcohol so easily?

Tags: analysis, breaking-bad

I can’t help but notice the scene in season 2, where Walter Jr. attempts to buy alcohol. His friends ask him to approach a man, outside of a gas station and ask if he would mind buying them some alcohol. This gentleman turns out to be an off-duty cop.

The scene that shortly followed is Walter Jr. being picked up by Hank. We are assuming that this gentleman was informed of Hank’s position by Walter Jr.. Hank is high up the ranks, but not too high, really. Does he have the power to not allow any charges to be pressed on the crime?

Comment: I'm curious if this is a crime.  I have it in my head that it's illegal to SELL to a minor but is it actually illegal (as in a fine/jail time) for BUYING as a minor?  Obviously drunk in public, open liquor laws, etc..., all of that still applies but did Walter Jr. actually commit a crime? Even soliciting someone to buy for you; I feel like the person buying for the minor would get in trouble, not the minor. Can anyone clarify? I'm Canadian, if this makes a difference between Canada and US.

Comment: @Kalmino, ['Every state makes it a crime for adults to aid a minor's act of delinquency. They differ but are generally similar in scope. For instance, most states will charge you with a misdemeanor if you offer to buy a case of beer for a teen or host a keg party attended by your teenage son and his friends. Some states, however, treat the crime as a felony in certain instances.'](http://criminal.findlaw.com/criminal-charges/contributing-to-the-delinquency-of-a-minor.html)

Comment: @NPresley you've just repeated what Kalmino said about the selling being a crime, but your quote says nothing about the attempted purchase...

Comment: @Kalmino ... laws vary by state.  In New Mexico it is illegal for a minor to purchase alcohol or even to possess alcohol with two exceptions https://www.newmexicocriminallaw.com/practice-areas/dui/dwi-minors/

Comment: Well strictly that document says Albuquerque or other cities.  I'm unsure of the exact scope, but it seems plausible that what Walt Jr was doing was strictly illegal. Yes he wasn't purchasing from the retailer, but I'm sure its argued that this kind of transaction is essentially a purchase, or even worse persuading someone else to commit a crime on your behalf.

Comment: @Kalmino yes the juvenile is guilty of a crime.  However the *juvenile* justice system works differently, with sort of a "reset" when you turn 18.  It's possible for a juvenile to be charged as an adult with full consequences and no reset button, but not for petty crimes that are juvenile by definition.

Comment: There is another scene where Walter is pulled over for speeding and refuses to comply and is thrown in jail (S3E2). He is then released from jail thanks to Hank going to the local police, making his case.

Comment: @e2-e4 ah, yes. Of course.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

My interpretation of this scene is not that Hank has the power to do this, but that he is able to talk "one law enforcement officer to another".  Hank is in the DEA, not the local police force, so although undoubtedly he would be considered more senior, I don't think he would be able to 'pull rank' to get Walt Jr out of trouble.

I don't believe that the cop was undercover, I think he was off-duty and happened to just be going into the gas station when he was interrupted by Walt Jr.

The cop probably wants to go back to enjoying his evening ... not dealing with a foolish kid buying alcohol.  Buying alcohol isn't exactly the most heinous crime.  I can imagine Hank promising to deal with him, and asking the cop to cut him some slack.

The fact that the cop could hand Walt Jr over to his responsible law enforcement "father" probably made the cop's life a lot simpler and he could go back to what he was doing.

Comment: This. I too believe it has nothing to do with Hank's specific position in the DEA but it's because he is also a law enforcer (and related to Walt jr) that is capable of dealing with a nephew / petty crime.

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the accepted answer — I don’t think Hank ever mentioned his job or pulled a favor with the off-duty cop. Remember that the cop tells Junior, “You're lucky you've got a good dad here”, meaning Hank, so I’d be surprised if Hank was even properly introduced to him, let alone announced his role as a federal law enforcement agent. This also clearly shows that Hank didn’t know this police officer, making it harder to get a favor from him.

I read the situation as the cop threatening to arrest Junior and making him call a parent as a way of scaring him away from criminal behavior. Since Junior was angry with his parents over Walt’s cancer diagnosis (and possibly just to avoid getting into trouble at home), he called Hank instead and introduced him as his father. Hank, upset at usurping Walt’s rightful role, quickly made his apologies and promised adequate punishment, and the cop let Junior go with a warning, impressed with the speed with which Hank responded and the care he showed towards Junior.

Comment: This is indeed possible too.  Both answers are downplaying the original premise of the question that Hank uses his *power* to get Walt Jr let off.  To my mind that's not what is shown - its impossible to say whether Hank ever makes the cop aware that he is also a law enforcement official or not, but he definitely doesn't "pull rank".

Comment: @iandotkelly Remember that there is a scene where we see Hank use his status as a LEO to help someone — he gets Walt out of trouble after he screams at a police officer and is pepper sprayed as a result.

Comment: @Gaurav yes indeed. I forgot about that one.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think we can tell whether or not Hank makes the cop aware that he's in law enforcement, whether or not he doesn't make it explicitly aware that he's the boy's uncle not his father.  We're both basically agreeing that he didn't explicitly pull rank - we can't really tell whether or not he made him aware that he was also in law enforcement or just pretended to be a responsible father.  I think its likely that Hank would subtly let the guy know.

Answer (score 3):

**Walt Jr. lied.** Hank openly supported the lie.   We don't know whether

- Walt Jr. managed to call Hank in advance to arrange it, or
- lied to the police claiming *Hank* was his father, and they called Hank and said "we have your son Walt" and Hank realized the game and decided to go along with it instead of bust it.

We don't know.  If the latter case, Walt Jr. *took a huge, huge gamble* and it paid off... not knowing which makes it interesting.

Regardless, the police were led to believe Walt Jr. was *Hank's son*, not Walter's.

The cops agreeing to drop it is a professional courtesy, cop to cop.  **It is not a "get out of jail free" card.**  They reasonably expect the father to handle the discipline problem "domestically", and not see that child in their station again.  This is reasonable practice, because they know what kind of person a cop is.

Breaking Bad didn't spend a lot of time with it, because it's a trope that most TV watchers will be familiar with.